# WAMP in Windows 8 (64 bit) doesn't work

Tags: php, apache, windows-8, wamp, wampserver

I've installed wampserver. Yet it is always as a red tray icon.

- Icon tooltip msg: `local server - None of 2 services running`.
- Port 80 is not occupied; checked with *Apache ► Service ► Test port 80*:

  > Warning: chmod(): Permission denied in C:\wamp\scripts\config.inc.php on line 68
  >   Impossible to modify the file C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts to be writab
  >   le
  >   The file C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts is not writable
  >   ***** Test which uses port 80 *****
  >   ===== Tested by command netstat filtered on port 80 =====
  >   Test for TCP
  >   Port 80 is not found associated with TCP protocol
  >   Test for TCPv6
  >   Port 80 is not found associated with TCP protocol
  >   ===== Tested by attempting to open a socket on port 80 =====
  >   **Your port 80 is not actually used**.
- *Apache ► Service administration ► Install Service* issues in a cmd window:
  [image] 
  **pressing *Enter* shuts the window down**, nothing happens. Waiting gives no profit either.

What's wrong?

### Update

- Had attempts to change port number for Apache (both to 81 and to 8080) in `httpd.conf`:

  Listen 0.0.0.0:8080 
  Listen [::0]:8080
  ServerName localhost:8080
- Checked whether IIS is runnig => No!
  [image].

Doesn't help.

Comment: I got the same problem recently, I tried with uWamp, same problem but if I using the 8080 port the problem seems to be solved.

Comment: @ThomasRollet, thakns Thomas. But again I've done it too. It does not avail...

Comment: Did you start WAMPServer normally "As Administrator" or did you try and run it as a normal user?

Comment: Did you also make sure you had all the required MSVC Runtime Libraries installed [See this Wampserver troubleshooting tips](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,134915) Specifically POINT20

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem, and the solution was too simple:

"Run it as Administrator."

- Without changing port or other additional configuration ...

You can do it by right clicking on the program icon and in the menu that appears, select the option "Run as administrator".

It is also possible to automate this process, by right clicking on the program icon and selecting "Properties".
Once the properties window is open, we go to the "Compatibility" tab. In the "Configuration" area we mark the option "Run this program as administrator".
Then we will click on "Apply" and then on "OK".
Ready! From now on, every time we run the program it will do so in administrator mode.

(Today, May 8, 2019, I see that @riggsfolly has responded in a comment much earlier than me. My recognition.)

Comment: This solved my issue. It was strange, as I had checked my wampserver.exe properties (under 'compatibility') to see if it should always run as administrator - this was set to true. Therefore I didn't think I had to manually start wampserver as administrator - but it turns out that's exactly what I had to do.

Comment: After trying a bunch of other things, this solved my issue as well... although in retrospect should have been obvious!

Comment: awesome. Confirmed here that not running as administrator 1 on 3 services are running. Running as admin 3 on 3 and working perfectly

Comment: Friends, since I started using Laragon (laragon.org) I never required the use of WAMP or XAMPP again. Unless someone needs to use a specific WAMP or XAMPP tool, Laragon is a simple solution for any use.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem, tried change port and so on, but finally I installed older version (2.5 I think) and it works without any change of setting.

Comment: I had the same issue, and older version worked for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think that IIS in install your windows
   Change your port on `httpd.conf`
for example 81

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen [::0]:80
ServerName localhost:80
```

to

```
  Listen 0.0.0.0:81
  Listen [::0]:81
  ServerName localhost:81
```

and restart apache service

Comment: Dose not work after change post? are sure IIS in not install?

Comment: how to make sure `IIS in not installed`?

Comment: see this link http://www.thewindowsclub.com/enable-turn-on-iis-internet-information-services

Comment: @paraniod, I've done it too: `set 4 instanses of 81 and apache service restart`. No avail...

Answer (score 0):

Open the httpd.exe in administration manually. The file is in `wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.23\bin\`. Then it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

1. Uninstall the wamp server
2. Click on the downloaded wamp file , and select `Run as Administrator`
3. Read and follow the `Information Window` that will pop up after one or two steps
4. Complete the installation
5. Still ? Check out http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,134915

Answer (score 0):

It can happen because of one of the three reasons:-

1) **Missing VC++ installation:** Install All versions of VC++ redistribution packages VC9, VC10, VC11, VC13, VC14 and VC15.. If you have a 64-bit Windows, you must install both 32 and 64bit versions of each VisualC++ package, even if you do not use Wampserver 64 bit.

2) **You forgot to provide Admin Privileges to WAMP Server** : Launch and Install with the **"Run as administrator"** option, very important.

3) **WAMP, IIS and Skype fighting over same port** :

- Close Skype or force not to use port 80: http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,134915
- Disable IIS: http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,134915